# Casting an ImmutableList to List

Tags: java, list, guava

Although my research was going in circles, it looks like Google Guava's `ImmutableList` implements `List`. So I can cast it up to a `List`, right? I know it will throw an error if one of the `List`'s modification methods are used, but is that all that can go wrong?

```
public List<Integer> getList() { 
    return ImmutableList.of(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: It *is* a `List`, but it's not clear why you'd *need* to cast it to a `List`.

Comment: *but is that all that can go wrong* -  What else do you want to go wrong??.. It does what it is meant to do...

Comment: the code you wrote already works as intended

Comment: Id like to cast it or pass it around as a List because the application I'm maintaining uses List everywhere, so I'd like to keep that flexibility rather than overhauling and replacing every List type with a ImmutableList type.

Comment: @ThomasN. - Then you can pass it. *because* an *ImmutableList* is also a *List*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it implements List, there's no need to cast it to `List`. You can assign it to a `List` variable or pass it to a method that expects a `List` without casting.

And, yes, calling any of the methods that modify a `List` would throw an exception, but it would happen regardless to whether or not you cast it to `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a bigger problem I don't think you understand. You can't cast an object *down* to the object type your object (ImmutableList) implements. `List<E>` is the interface to `ImmutableList`. You can cast it as type `List<E>`, but you'd lose everything ImmutableList has/provides that List doesn't.

Comment: No comment explaining what's wrong with my answer? It's not explicitly answering OP's question, but it does point out something in his logic.

Comment: It seems totally incorrect to me.  You *can* cast an object to the type it implements (`List<String> bar = (List<String>) ImmutableList.of("bar");`).  In fact the cast is normally redundant.  And there's no such thing as a "new instance of type `List`" since `List` is an interface.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't cast it. I said you couldn't cast down. OP made it sound like the implemented interface was lower in the hierarchy when it's above. Maybe it was just the semantics of his wording and how I noticed nobody was adding `<E>` into anything making it seem like `List` and `List<E>` were the same. Also `List<String> bar = (List<String>) ImmutableList.of("bar");` describes exactly what I said. `bar` is your new instance of type `List<String>`.

Comment: Okay you're right that a down-cast to an interface makes no sense in this case.  But `bar` is not a new instance, it's the same instance.  And since `List` and `List<E>` are the same (raw) type in Java, they're often used interchangeably.

Comment: @TavianBarnes >.< yes. you're right. Since ImmutableList is a List, typecasting to a List still makes it the same instance of a List. My bad!